How to create a List Tile of checkbox from key value map. Flutter/Dart
I have data from the API as below

I want to generate the UI using List Tile or whatever method which will satisfy below UI requirement.
COMPETITION is Header 1 from the API
Competition Matrix and Training Matrix as Cat 1 and Cat 2.


Please see example
    final items = {
      'Header 1': ['Cat 1', 'Cat2'],
      'Header 2': ['Cat 1', 'Cat2'],
    };
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        for (var item in items.entries)
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                item.key,
                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
              ...item.value.map(
                (e) => Text(
                  e,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );

This is results

